# exp_flash cookie being set for each channel entry

Tags: cookies

I have a CE tag that seems to be setting the exp_flash cookie to the entire contents of each entry output within the loop. This leads to an error in chrome, where the header ends up being too large.

Set-Cookie: exp_flash=a%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A17%3A%22%3Anew%3Agmap_tagdata%22%3Bs%3A6787%3A%22%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%7Bexp%3Ace_cache%3Ait+id%3D%22%7Bauthor_id%7Dpost%7Bentry_id%7D%22+url_override%3D%22user%7Bauthor_id%7D%2Fpost%22%7D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cli+class%3D%22post%7Bif+c_photo%7D+hasPhoto%7B%2Fif%7D%7Bif+c_desc%7D+hasEvent%7B%2Fif%7D%22+data-id%3D%22%7Bentry_id%7D%22+data-author_id%3D%22%7Bauthor_id%7D%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cheader%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cdiv+class%3D%22mTime%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7Bentry_date%3Arelative%7D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7Bif+c_desc%3D%3D%22%22%7D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cdiv+class%3D%22mImage%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7Bexp%3Ace_img%3Apair+src%3D%22%7Bphoto_url%7D%22+rounded_corners%3D%22all%2C25%22+border%3D%223%7Cffffff%22+height%3D%2250%22++width%3D%2250%22+crop%3D%22yes%22+allow_scale_larger%3D%22yes%22+save_type%3D%22png%22%7D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Ca+href%3D%22%2Fmember%2F%7Bauthor_id%7D%22%3E%3Cimg+src%3D%22%7Bmade%7D%22+alt%3D%27%7Btitle%7D%27%2F%3E%3C%2Fa%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7B%2Fexp%3Ace_img%3Apair%7D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

etc etc this repeats for each entry output on the page.
Not clear why this would be set, I've toggled extensions and plugins, etc to no end. Anybody know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be an issue with EE 2.8, MSM, and google maps for expressionengine. 
Updated Google maps module to 3.3.5 and all is well