# Response header too large

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, error-500

The response header for one of my pages is too large, some browsers to throw a 500 error, and preventing me from using W3C HTML validation:
http://example.com/water-softener-reviews

I have a (very long) line for each channel entry beginning (viewing using Web Developer in Firefox):

```
exp_flash=a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A17%3A%22%3Aold...
```

I notice one line says expiry is 1997 - not sure if that's normal:

```
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 17:09:29 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 11092
Keep-Alive: timeout=100, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I can't find any information that suggests a solution to this, other than the user needs to increase is header response size limit. The header is so large I don't think increasing the limit is a valid solution.

Any suggestions for a fix?

EE version is 2.7.2.

Comment: Have a look at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20481/exp-flash-cookie-being-set-for-each-channel-entry

Comment: Yep, it was a bug in Google Maps module 3.3.2. Thank you!